# Typescript: What is the type of React Router Link

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm passing `Link` from `react-router-dom` as props, And need to define it in the interface.
When hovering over the Link element, I see that it's of type:

```
React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<LinkProps & React.RefAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>>
```

But I don't understand what that `LinkProps` is,
I tried to define the type as:

```
React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<HTMLElement>;
```

And a few other options, but I always get the error that the type of

```
React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<LinkProps & React.RefAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>>
```

Is not assignable to the type I'm trying to use. It only works with:

```
React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<any>;
```

How can I find out the correct type?

Comment: which version you are using?

Comment: Version of ts ? 4.8.2

Comment: version of react router

Comment: Also share how you are using it

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
React.forwardRef<HTMLAnchorElement, LinkProps>
```

Comment: Thanks no it still says it's not assignable to this type (I removed LinkProps because I was required to use only one argument btw)